# ftp multiple files to another server via loop

Tags: curl, ftp, lftp

I try to transfer huge amount(578) of file among of 774 files with ftp. I have the file name which should transfer. the file name format is like : 
**TS_20170818_171102_17.csv** and it's not a in same pattern which means I should copy file name in somewhere.

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? Don't you know how to put files on `ftp` server or how to specify them?

Comment: My problem is how to specify those files that should be transfer as they are not in a similar pattern

Comment: Are all this files in the same directory? Are they all `*.csv`?

Answer (score -1):

If those files are in the same folder, you can simply upload them like this:

> put /path/to/files/*